# Adding column values together to form 1 result column

Tags: mysql

I have an online sales system I am developing and I’m working on the billing payment system.

I have the order total $ amount recorded on the database table with the order itself.

**Example:**

```
SELECT total FROM Orders WHERE id = '1'
```

Then, I’ve got another table that includes an individual record for each financial transaction (check, cc, etc.)

**Example:**

```
SELECT payment_amount FROM Payments WHERE order_id = '1'
```

What I would like to do is combine these two together when doing some reporting of which orders have not been paid in full and retrieve the balance of each order.  I’d like to do this with a single query if possible...

This was what I tried...

```
SELECT o.id as order_id, o.total, (SELECT p.payment_amount FROM Payments as p WHERE o.order_id = o.id) as amount_paid_plus FROM Orders as o
```

This works great if there is only 1 entry in payments...but if there are two, I get this error

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

**I want the payments table results to be added together into one lump sum amount and returned as one variable in the query**

I also need the query to still return info even if there are no payments in the payments table.  It will just display amount paid as 0.

Comment: You can just change `p.payment_amount` to `SUM(p.payment_amount)`

Comment: Perfect!  It’s funny I was just thinking “I bet there has to be a sum() option...I mean, everything has a sum() option....haha

Comment: Make that an answer and I’ll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change `p.payment_amount` to `SUM(p.payment_amount)` in your subquery. Note that you have an error in the subquery, it should probably be

```
(SELECT SUM(p.payment_amount) FROM Payments as p WHERE p.order_id = o.id)
```

Note change from `o.order_id` to `p.order_id`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.  I changed the actual query on here to make more sense because the one I have has  a lot more irrelevent information being pulled.  Also, If I’ve got p.payment_aount and another column o.amount_paid.  Is there a way to add those two together in the query as a separate value?

Comment: I presume `o.amount_paid` is in the `orders` table, and there is only one value per order? If so, you could write `amount_paid + (SELECT SUM(p.payment_amount) FROM Payments as p WHERE p.order_id = o.id) AS total_paid_amount` or something similar

Comment: Would it be (o.amount_paid + sum(p.payment_amount)) as total_paid_amount

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
SELECT o.id, o.total, SUM(p.payment_amount) FROM Orders o, Payments p where p.order_id = o.id
```